# I'm Trying to Convert an str & join it with a command to iterate in a for loop. When I use %s it enters one word. With %r it add a "u" I don't want

Tags: python

WARNING: This will try to download mp3s from YouTube, so be ready to hit ctrl+Z.
The problem spots are at the bottom of the code. I have a feeling it could be rewritten in a simpler way.
This is supposed to store titles and enter whole titles in a search field. When I use %s in the for loop it breaks down every word in the title and searches them individually. When I use %r it searches the entire title but it puts a "u" at the beginning. EXAMPLE: Instead of searching Abby Road, it searches uAbby Road.

```
import youtube_dl
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ('http://pitchfork.com/reviews/best/albums/?page=1')
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
all = (result.content.decode('utf-8'))

soup = BeautifulSoup(all, "lxml")

h = []

for element in soup.select('h2'):
    h.append(element.get_text())

for i in h[1:10]:
    print i

for i in h[1:10]:

    k4 = ('youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 128K --default-search=ytsearch: %r ') % (i)
    k5 = (''.join(map(str,k4)))
    os.system(k5)
```

This is what I get in the commandline...
When I use %s instead of %r it only searches one word at a time

(venv) MY-MacBook-Pro:tube ME$ python mp.py
Nothing Feels Natural
Culture
I See You
Run the Jewels 3
Before the Dawn
We got it from Here... Thank You 4 Your service
You Want It Darker
Front Row Seat to Earth
Yes Lawd!
[youtube:search] query "uNothing Feels Natural": Downloading page 1
[download] Downloading playlist: uNothing Feels Natural...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` operator takes an iterable, which a string is, so you need to use an iterable (say, a tuple) that *contains* the string.

```
k4 = ('youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 128K --default-search=ytsearch: %s '
      % (i,)
```

That said, use `subprocess.call` instead of `os.system`.

```
for i in h[1:10]:
    subprocess.call(["youtube-dl", "-x",
                     "--audio-format", "mp3",
                     "--audio-quality", "128K",
                     "--default-search", "ytsearch",
                     i])
```